# Duplicating or Replicating pattern for php

Tags: php

I would like to duplicate the pattern, the function will have 2 parameters, which is row and column. It will duplicate the pattern on how many rows and columns. My function for pattern is correct but how can I duplicate/replicate it. Should I make it in array? Thanks

```
<?php

$row_col_array = array();

function honey(){
    $l = "";

    for($i=2; $i<=4; $i++)
    {
     for($j=4; $j>=2; $j--)
     {
      if($i == $j)
       echo  "*";
      else
       echo "&nbsp;&nbsp;";
     }
     for($k=2; $k<=4; $k++)
     {
      if($i == $k)
      echo  "*";
      else
       echo "&nbsp;&nbsp;";
     }
     echo "<br>";
    }

    for($i=4; $i>=2; $i--)
    {
     for($j=4; $j>=2; $j--)
     {
      if($i == $j)
        echo "*";
      else
        echo "&nbsp;&nbsp;";
     }
     for($k=2; $k<=4; $k++)
     {
      if($i == $k)
        echo  "*";
      else
        echo "&nbsp;&nbsp;";
     }
     echo "<br>";
    }
}

honey();


?>
```

Comment: This appears to still be pretty much the same question you already asked yesterday, [Pattern HoneyComb duplicating pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72356176/pattern-honeycomb-duplicating-pattern)

Comment: FYI, this has nothing to do with Codeigniter.

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).